# Tradeback error and NameError python

Tags: python, nameerror, traceback

I'm trying to enter a value between 1-9 and then print the word version of the number the user entered. I keep getting a traceback error and name error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Michell/Desktop/testq1.1.py", line 13, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/Michell/Desktop/testq1.1.py", line 11, in main
    print (fun(num))
  File "/Users/Michell/Desktop/testq1.1.py", line 3, in fun
    word2num = numlist[num-1]
NameError: name 'numlist' is not defined*
```

My code is below:

```
def fun(num):

      word2num = numlist[num-1]
      return numlist
      return num

def main():

      num = eval(input("Enter a # between 1-9: "))
      numlist = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"]
      print (fun(num))

main()
```

Comment: You are using numlist in the fun() function, but you never passed the numlist as an argument.

Comment: `numlist` isn't local to your `fun`... it's only local to `main`, and isn't at all global. You can try using `global numlist; numlist = ['one', 'two', ...]`, but there are much better ways to get around this, such as passing `numlist` as a parameter to `fun`

Comment: why use eval if you want an **int**

Comment: By the way, `return numlist; return num` will not return num. Once `return` executes successfully, the function exits. You should use `return numlist, num`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `numlist` to your `fun` function and return the `word2num` rather than the whole list:

```
def fun(num, numlist):
    word2num = numlist[num - 1]
    return word2num

def main():
    num = int(input("Enter a # between 1-9: "))
    numlist = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]

    print(fun(num, numlist))

main()
```